# Slick2D button released and call a function

Tags: java, position, mouse, slick2d

I tried to create a rectangle(as a button), then use the mouse position to check if the mouse is at the button then quit the game.

Here is what i tried

```
if(Mouse.isButtonDown(0)) {
    downFlag = true;
}

if ((posX>120 && posX<420)&&(posY>120 && posY<180)) {
    if (!Mouse.isButtonDown(0) && downFlag) {
        gc.exit();
    }
}
```

But if i click the mouse outside of the button, and then move my mouse to the button, it is still registered as the mouse clicked the button itself.
Do i need to add a timer to check how long has the mouse been released? Like turn the `downFlag` to false after a few miliseconds the mouse have been clicked?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `Input`'s `isMousePressed(Input.MOUSE_LEFT_BUTTON)` inside the bounds check.
If you don't like the feel of it, use your current method, but add a bounds check where you check for mouse down the first time. It requires a lot of bookkeeping though, if you have multiple buttons.